# Accessing Pyomo user time with Neos

Tags: pyomo

I teach an optimization course in which I use the Pyomo modeling language to solve problems. I also encourage students to compare solvers using Neos. However, I have not found a way to measure the computational time required to solve the problems.
To explain my point I have created this notebook in Colab (https://github.com/salvapineda/notebooks/blob/main/UserTimePyomoNeos.ipynb)
First, I solve a model using cbc without using NEOS. As you can see, the "Solver Information" includes the time required to solve the problem.
Then, I solve the same model using cbc through NEOS. However, the "Solver Information" does not include any time information.
Is there any way to access the computational time when I am solving Pyomo models in Neos?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the breakdown of the computation time? The model  in Colab on NEOS returns 0.00389 seconds.

---

Message: CBC 2.10.3 optimal, objective 3.49; 0 nodes, 2 iterations, 0.00389 seconds

Comment: you're right, but you cannot access such time and use it as a variable, for example. At least, I do not know how to do it.